# Changing system sounds in Mac OS X

Tags: macos

I would like to change system sounds for certain events in Mac OS X.

How do I do this?

I want to replate "Basso", "Bottle", "Submarine" and another sounds to my own.

The types of sounds: when mail comes, when iCal notification fires, when in terminal i press tab etc.

Comment: Do you mean Mac OS 9, or do you talk about OS X ?

Comment: What sort of events?

Comment: I mean Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple document this in [Apple knowledge base.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta20512?viewlocale=en_us)

You add a file in .aiff format into ~/Library/Sounds for just you as user requiring normal permissions or if you want to share the sound with other users in /Library/Sounds which will require admin permissions. (Never change things in /System/Library as this is for Apple's use only and will get altered by software updates. ) If you are on a network then /Network/Library/Sounds might also work

Comment: Mp3 files also work (at least as far as I've tested in Snow Leopard)

Comment: Mark, point taken about losing the sounds to an update, appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Is there a way to change sounds other than the alert sound? I used to be able to change all the system sounds ...

Comment: @MaxRocket That is a separate question